# Two-column grid, with right column having two rows

Tags: html, css, drupal, flexbox

I have a CSS question. I'm using Drupal and I can't just put in a `<br />` so I have to use CSS to fix this problem.

For my individual articles on my site I'm displaying the photo of the author of the article as well as their name and their role in the organization, so ideally it would look like this on the page (imagine the IMG 'block' is just one giant image):

```
IMG
IMG  by Author Name
IMG  Author Role
IMG
```

So that's **one** image on the left and the name and role on the right, the role right underneath the name.

**However**, what I've got instead is the following, and I can't figure out how to make a simple line break basically:

```
IMG
IMG by Author Name Author Role
IMG
IMG
```

The whole thing (image, as well as name, and role) is within a `<div>`. The `<div>` is `text-align: center`. The individual items within the `<div>` are also in their own `<div>` and are set as `display: inline-block` (so the overall `<div>` can be aligned center).

**I can't figure out how to put Author Role on its own line directly beneath Author Name while still to the right of the image!**

I've tried floating the Author Role, changing it's display to block and flex and inline...and nothing seems to work. The role either gets put below the `<div>` altogether or it just stays to the right of the Author Name.

Here's my markup:

```
// <div> around author photo, name, and title
.group-left {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.field-name-ds-user-picture {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;

    // style actual photo to be a certain size and alignment
    img {
        width: 65px;
        height: 65px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}

// styling of author name - make block
.field-name-author {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 22px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.field-name-display-suite-role {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Does anyone know how to make the Role just go to the next line under the Name but still to the right of the image?

Comment: Are you able to wrap the author and role in their own container? If so, then is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/ao78019c/

Comment: @JusticeErolin I added my markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the layout with [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box image">IMAGE</div>
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="box author_name">by Author Name</div>
        <div class="box author_role">Author Role</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** (includes non-essential decorative styles for demo)

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 300px;
}

.box {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.image {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.author_name,
.author_role {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

The code above renders this layout:

[image]

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/o0v9861o/)